# Realm crashing sometimes on initialization

Tags: swift, realm

I received some reports from the app-store that Realm crashes on initialization, but without any details. My hope is that someone (from Realm team?) can see what could be the problem.

Here is how I create an instance:

```
 func loadRealm() -> Realm {

        if let realm = self.realm {
            return realm
        }

        if let _ = NSClassFromString("XCTest"){
            realm =  try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(fileURL: nil, inMemoryIdentifier: "test", syncConfiguration: nil, encryptionKey: nil, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: currentSchemaVersion, migrationBlock: nil, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, objectTypes: nil))
        } else {
            realm =  try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: nil, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: currentSchemaVersion, migrationBlock: nil, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, objectTypes: nil))
        }
        return realm!
    }
```

It happpens in the line executed when it is not a test. The error is "swift_unexpectedError".

Comment: You should definitely try 

do { let realm = try Realm() } catch let error { print(error) } and edit your question.

Comment: why should that help? it just catches the exception. But I need to have a realm instance

Comment: It's going to be difficult for anyone to do more than guess without seeing the exact error that the Realm initializer is raising.